# XSL transformation - use XML from online resource

Tags: xml, xslt, proxy

I'm trying to make XSL file that updates existing XML file with data from online XML resource.

Original XML file and XSL are on localhost (which uses http), and my online resource (another XML file that contains new content) is on https://example.com/xml/update.xml

XSL looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                          xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"
                          xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco"                      
                 http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20060504/srv/srv.xsd">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Identity template, copies everything as is -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Override for target element -->
  <xsl:template match="gmd:MD_DataIdentification/gmd:citation/gmd:CI_Citation">
    <!-- Copy the element -->
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- And everything inside it -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="document('https://example.com/xml/update.xml')/newData">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm getting the following error when I view the XML file on localhost:
`Unsafe attempt to load URL https://example.com/xml/update.xml from frame with URL http://localhost/tutorial/metadata/ENVI_Natura2000.xml. Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

Is there any way I can modify my XSL document to bypass this?

Comment: Which tool do you use to run the XSLT? Such an error is usually raised by browsers like Firefox or Chrome but certainly not by stand-alone XSLT processors like Saxon, xsltproc or any XML IDE like oXygen, Altova or StylusStudio. Your XSLT code says `version="2.0"` which browsers do not support anyway. Depending on the browser setting up `example.com` for CORS might help but I am not sure how well they have integrated that in their XSLT stacks.

Comment: I'm using Chrome to test this.

Comment: Chrome is just for testing, this is intended to be used in GeoNetwork, but testing is easier with Chrome. I tested it in GeonNetwork now and it works. So, you propose using XSLT processor for testing?  I rarely work with XML (sorry if question is dumb).

Comment: I don't know what GeonNetwork is but in general, trying to develop XSLT by testing it inside a desktop browser is not a good idea in my view as browsers restrict some features and don't provide good error diagnostics when it comes to XSLT. I would recommend using a stand-alone XSLT processor or an XML IDE or I think most general development IDEs or editors do come with or allow installation of an XSLT plugin.

Comment: Of course given that there are three version of XSLT (1.0 from 1999, 2.0 from 2007 and 3.0 from 2017) and various tools depend on a particular XSLT processor it is a good idea to find out which one GeonNetwork uses and try to use an editor or IDE that allows using it as a plugin.